Automatic backup deletion?
I backup servers to a network share, all is well. But one backup must be kept so I move it to a new folder and rename it, this should keep the backup indefinitely but I'm wondering if it got auto cleaned?
The path in question is typically
"\backupnode\SQL_Backups\sqlservername\dbname\full\backupnamewithdatetime.BAK"
Moved and renamed to
"\backupnode\SQL_Backups\sqlservername\dbname\do not delete\backupnamewithdate-additonaltext.BAK"
Would this have been cleared by the maintenance script?

How can anyone tell you what the maintenance script might do without seeing the maintenance script?

Each maintenance plan clearly defines which directories (and any sub-directories) will be parsed to delete previous backup files.  I suspect the "default" (when the plan was created) may well be (in your case) the "dbname" directory (and all sub-directories) - however, you will only know by looking at the actual maintenance plan.  Every plan, on every SQL Server, can be different

If you are using the default hola hallengren cleanup script your backup is placed in a safe area.
I have tested that this path is safe for sure:
"\backupnode\Historic_Backups\sqlservername\dbname\full\backupnamewithdate-additonaltext.BAK".
To be sure, create a new db, set a backup for that one with cleaunp of one hour and the run the backup a couple of time and see the results.

Yup @MBuschi the script in use as the tags on the post indicates is Ola hallengren - the path difference starts from "full" rather than further up the chain
